# Writing to file and mkdir race conditions C

Tags: c++, linux, race-condition, mkdir

I made a function that tries to create a directory, and then write a simple file:

```
buffer = "Hello world!";
string url = "a/b/c/d/";
string tmp = "";
string done = "";
while((tmp = GetBaseDir(url)).compare("")!=0){
    done+=tmp;
    mkdir(done.c_str(), 0777);
} // GetBaseDir returns "a/", and changes url to "b/c/d/"
ofstream file;
file.open((url+"file.txt").c_str(),ios::trunc);
file << buffer;
file.close();
```

As you can see, it only tries, if there is a failure it just keeps going on.

I read that 'open' will fail if another process opened that same file with write permissions. But, is this true?
What happens with mkdir and the write operation if I run several instances of this code at the same time?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: EDIT:
I haven't tried to reproduce that race condition. I want to know whether mkdir executes reliably, or I have to use a mutex to protect it. As well as the write operation in c++.

When I search this problem, instead of finding something related I find more questions or information on how to use mkdir http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir, not how it works. The documentation pages don't mention race conditions.

What I've found on write operations with race conditions isn't helpful either. They mention what race conditions are with different examples, but I already know that.

Comment: I found that I could protect the file by using open with the options O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL. But again, I'm not sure if that's enough or I have to use a mutex to make sure that works properly.

Comment: When you use O_EXCL, the file will be created atomically, and any other simultaneous, exclusive open calls with fail. It's basically a mutex in itself.

Comment: Thanks, do you know anything about mkdir? My assumption is that it is reliable, since it's in the linux API. Although, I'm not really sure.

Comment: If you're not experiencing a problem, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The man page notes mkdir fails when the directory already exists.  It returns -1 rather than 0.  If you ignore that, your code will usually work OK, as long as a/b/c/d are actually directories.  A competing process could create them as something else, resulting in an error.  It's not clear why you use mode 0777, since it would be far better to use 0700 or even 0770 with a special group.  If you are sure they will always be directories, then every instance of the code will ensure that the dir path exists, and the only contention will be on creating the file.

```
NAME
   mkdir -- make a directory file
SYNOPSIS
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
RETURN VALUES
   A 0 return value indicates success.  A -1 return value indicates an
   error, and an error code is stored in errno.
ERRORS
     Mkdir() will fail and no directory will be created if:
   ...
   [EEXIST]           The named file exists.
```