# Handling mkdir when directory exists (C language)

Tags: c, error-handling, mkdir

I'm trying to get a function made that will create a directory for use in a program, but will fail nicely when the directory already exists. Right now I'm doing

```
if (mkdir(path, RW)<0)
{
error out and return
}
```

My problem is that mkdir returns -1 for what I think of as "real errors" (no access, no space, etc..) as well as for the directory already existing. I do want to error out in every error case aside from directory already exists. Any advice?

Reference:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir

Comment: You should see `man errno` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). At http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir, you can see the return value. If has an error will be -1 and `errno` will be set.

Comment: You should stat the path and see if that returns success.  One thing to look out for is when the path exists already, but it's a file and not a directory.  Stat will tell you that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do the [`mkdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html) first, since doing a [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) first will be more vulnerable to race conditions.  On the line where you have

```
error out and return
```

you should check first if `errno` is `EEXIST` (which would occur if there was already a file or directory), and in that special case, do a `stat` to determine if there was actually a directory (versus a file or special device, etc).

A race-condition refers to scenarios where more than one process is creating, deleting and using the directories (or files).  For example:

- [Writing to file and mkdir race conditions C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865338/writing-to-file-and-mkdir-race-conditions-c)
- [race condition between mkdir and stat #92](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp/pull/92)
- [Issue 1736:     MkdirAll race condition](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=1736)

Answer (score 1):

basically this is what I do:

```
errno = 0;
int dir_result = mkdir(dir_path, 0755);
if(dir_result != 0 && errno != EEXIST){
    //errors here   
}
else{
    //your code here
}
```

Regards.